# How to use http.DefaultTransport with one or two values changed

Tags: http, go

Let's say I want to use all of the values from Go's `http.DefaultTransport` or `http.DefaultClient`, *except* I want to set the MaxIdleConns parameter to 5. What is the best way to do that?

```
t := http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport)
t.MaxIdleConns = 5
```

manipulates http.DefaultTransport for every other caller.

```
t := new(http.Transport)
*t = *http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport)
t.MaxIdleConns = 5
```

Does what I want but seems very convoluted. Is that really the simplest way?

Comment: The second option is not valid. You can either crate your own transport, or modify the `DefaultTransport`.

Comment: Can you describe what's not valid about it? Seems to compile just fine. https://play.golang.org/p/U7BzWUfMGa2

Comment: If you press "Run" on that you will see: "assignment copies lock value to *tr: net/http.Transport contains sync.Mutex". This is why there's a Clone() method.

Answer (score 4):

Oh, there's a Clone() method.

```
tr := http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).Clone()
tr.MaxIdleConns = 37
```